# How was MG-Excelsus able to flip itself back to be standing?

Tags: metal-gear-rising

In the bossfight, Raiden is shown flipping Excelsus and then tearing off one of it's blades.[image]

And once it cuts back to Excelsus, it's rightside up, and remains that way until Armstrong obliterates it in the cutscene.
[image]

Comment: It's not definitive, but my read on it is that the Excelsus landed on a slight incline, and was thus able to readily push itself up. It didn't invert the body, or anything silly like that, because you can see that Raiden takes off the left blade, and indeed, when upright, the left blade is shown severed.

Comment: *Metal Gear Solid*, to the best of my knowledge, is not a franchise that thrives on realism or making sense.

Comment: I'm gonna take a wild guess and say *nanomachines*.